# Too many connections to 212.192.255.240

Tags: tcpip, malware, connection

Recently my Internet slowed down drastically. I downloaded a tool to see the TCP/IP connections from my Vista computer. I found that a lot of TCP/IP connections are being made to 212.192.255.240 through SVCHost. It seems that it is trying to connect to different ports.

I think that my computer is infected with some kind of malware but I am unsure how to get rid of it. I did a little bit of research on this IP but found nothing.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**
This is the HiJackThis log file - I can't find anything weird. I found the program is also trying to create connections to 91.205.127.63, which is in Russia.

```
    Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.4
Scan saved at 18:20:54 PM, on 4/29/2010
Platform: Windows Vista SP2 (WinNT 6.00.1906)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v8.00 (8.00.6001.18882)
Boot mode: Normal

Running processes:
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\taskeng.exe
C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Taskmgr.exe
C:\Windows\explorer.exe
C:\Windows\System32\igfxpers.exe
C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\ashDisp.exe
C:\Program Files\Software602\Print2PDF\Print2PDF.exe
C:\Windows\system32\igfxsrvc.exe
C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Vertrigo.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jusched.exe
C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleToolbarNotifier\GoogleToolbarNotifier.exe
C:\Windows\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpnscfg.exe
C:\Program Files\X-NetStat Professional\xns5.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
C:\Program Files\HP\Digital Imaging\smart web printing\hpswp_clipbook.exe
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
C:\Program Files\Trend Micro\HiJackThis\HiJackThis.exe

R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = about:blank
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch = 
R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings,ProxyServer = 10.0.0.30:8118
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
R3 - URLSearchHook: Yahoo! Toolbar - {EF99BD32-C1FB-11D2-892F-0090271D4F88} - C:\Program Files\Yahoo!\Companion\Installs\cpn0\yt.dll
F2 - REG:system.ini: Shell=explorer.exe rundll32.exe
O2 - BHO: &Yahoo! Toolbar Helper - {02478D38-C3F9-4efb-9B51-7695ECA05670} - C:\Program Files\Yahoo!\Companion\Installs\cpn0\yt.dll
O2 - BHO: HP Print Enhancer - {0347C33E-8762-4905-BF09-768834316C61} - C:\Program Files\HP\Digital Imaging\Smart Web Printing\hpswp_printenhancer.dll
O2 - BHO: AcroIEHelperStub - {18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelperShim.dll
O2 - BHO: RoboForm BHO - {724d43a9-0d85-11d4-9908-00400523e39a} - C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\roboform.dll
O2 - BHO: Groove GFS Browser Helper - {72853161-30C5-4D22-B7F9-0BBC1D38A37E} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office12\GRA8E1~1.DLL
O2 - BHO: Google Toolbar Helper - {AA58ED58-01DD-4d91-8333-CF10577473F7} - C:\Program Files\Google\Google Toolbar\GoogleToolbar_32.dll
O2 - BHO: Google Toolbar Notifier BHO - {AF69DE43-7D58-4638-B6FA-CE66B5AD205D} - C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleToolbarNotifier\5.5.4723.1820\swg.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper - {DBC80044-A445-435b-BC74-9C25C1C588A9} - C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll
O2 - BHO: Google Gears Helper - {E0FEFE40-FBF9-42AE-BA58-794CA7E3FB53} - C:\Program Files\Google\Google Gears\Internet Explorer\0.5.36.0\gears.dll
O2 - BHO: SingleInstance Class - {FDAD4DA1-61A2-4FD8-9C17-86F7AC245081} - C:\Program Files\Yahoo!\Companion\Installs\cpn0\YTSingleInstance.dll
O2 - BHO: HP Smart BHO Class - {FFFFFFFF-CF4E-4F2B-BDC2-0E72E116A856} - C:\Program Files\HP\Digital Imaging\Smart Web Printing\hpswp_BHO.dll
O3 - Toolbar: Yahoo! Toolbar - {EF99BD32-C1FB-11D2-892F-0090271D4F88} - C:\Program Files\Yahoo!\Companion\Installs\cpn0\yt.dll
O3 - Toolbar: &RoboForm - {724d43a0-0d85-11d4-9908-00400523e39a} - C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\roboform.dll
O3 - Toolbar: Google Toolbar - {2318C2B1-4965-11d4-9B18-009027A5CD4F} - C:\Program Files\Google\Google Toolbar\GoogleToolbar_32.dll
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [RtHDVCpl] C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RtHDVCpl.exe -s
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [IgfxTray] C:\Windows\system32\igfxtray.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Persistence] C:\Windows\system32\igfxpers.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [avast!] C:\PROGRA~1\ALWILS~1\Avast4\ashDisp.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Print2PDF Print Monitor] "C:\Program Files\Software602\Print2PDF\Print2PDF.exe" /server
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [VertrigoServ] "C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Vertrigo.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jusched.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe Reader Speed Launcher] "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe ARM] "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Google Quick Search Box] "C:\Program Files\Google\Quick Search Box\GoogleQuickSearchBox.exe"  /autorun
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [iTunesHelper] "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunesHelper.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [QuickTime Task] "C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTTask.exe" -atboottime
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [swg] "C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleToolbarNotifier\GoogleToolbarNotifier.exe"
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [CCProxy] C:\CCProxy\CCProxy.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [AlcoholAutomount] "C:\Program Files\Alcohol Soft\Alcohol 120\axcmd.exe" /automount
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [RoboForm] "C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboTaskBarIcon.exe"
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [FileHippo.com] "C:\Program Files\filehippo.com\UpdateChecker.exe" /background
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /detectMem (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [WindowsWelcomeCenter] rundll32.exe oobefldr.dll,ShowWelcomeCenter (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /detectMem (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O4 - Startup: AutorunsDisabled
O4 - Startup: Locate32 Autorun.lnk = C:\Program Files\Locate\Locate32.exe
O4 - Startup: OneNote Table Of Contents.onetoc2
O8 - Extra context menu item: Add to Google Photos Screensa&ver - res://C:\Windows\system32\GPhotos.scr/200
O8 - Extra context menu item: Customize Menu - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComCustomizeIEMenu.html
O8 - Extra context menu item: E&xport to Microsoft Excel - res://C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office14\EXCEL.EXE/3000
O8 - Extra context menu item: Fill Forms - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComFillForms.html
O8 - Extra context menu item: Google Sidewiki... - res://C:\Program Files\Google\Google Toolbar\Component\GoogleToolbarDynamic_mui_en_96D6FF0C6D236BF8.dll/cmsidewiki.html
O8 - Extra context menu item: RoboForm Toolbar - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComShowToolbar.html
O8 - Extra context menu item: S&end to OneNote - res://C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office14\ONBttnIE.dll/105
O8 - Extra context menu item: Save Forms - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComSavePass.html
O9 - Extra button: (no name) - {09C04DA7-5B76-4EBC-BBEE-B25EAC5965F5} - C:\Program Files\Google\Google Gears\Internet Explorer\0.5.36.0\gears.dll
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: &Gears Settings - {09C04DA7-5B76-4EBC-BBEE-B25EAC5965F5} - C:\Program Files\Google\Google Gears\Internet Explorer\0.5.36.0\gears.dll
O9 - Extra button: Send to OneNote - {2670000A-7350-4f3c-8081-5663EE0C6C49} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office12\ONBttnIE.dll
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: S&end to OneNote - {2670000A-7350-4f3c-8081-5663EE0C6C49} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office12\ONBttnIE.dll
O9 - Extra button: Fill Forms - {320AF880-6646-11D3-ABEE-C5DBF3571F46} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComFillForms.html
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Fill Forms - {320AF880-6646-11D3-ABEE-C5DBF3571F46} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComFillForms.html
O9 - Extra button: Save - {320AF880-6646-11D3-ABEE-C5DBF3571F49} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComSavePass.html
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Save Forms - {320AF880-6646-11D3-ABEE-C5DBF3571F49} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComSavePass.html
O9 - Extra button: Print2PDF - {5B7027AD-AA6D-40df-8F56-9560F277D2A5} - C:\Program Files\Software602\Print2PDF\Print602.dll
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Print2PDF - {5B7027AD-AA6D-40df-8F56-9560F277D2A5} - C:\Program Files\Software602\Print2PDF\Print602.dll
O9 - Extra button: RoboForm - {724d43aa-0d85-11d4-9908-00400523e39a} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComShowToolbar.html
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: RoboForm Toolbar - {724d43aa-0d85-11d4-9908-00400523e39a} - file://C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\AI RoboForm\RoboFormComShowToolbar.html
O9 - Extra button: Research - {92780B25-18CC-41C8-B9BE-3C9C571A8263} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office12\REFIEBAR.DLL
O9 - Extra button: Show or hide HP Smart Web Printing - {DDE87865-83C5-48c4-8357-2F5B1AA84522} - C:\Program Files\HP\Digital Imaging\Smart Web Printing\hpswp_BHO.dll
O17 - HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{A80AB385-7767-4B5C-AF97-DBD65B29D8D1}: NameServer = 218.248.255.146 218.248.255.212
O17 - HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{D10402C1-9CDE-4582-A6B7-6C0D33B0E7BC}: NameServer = 218.248.255.146,218.248.255.212
O18 - Protocol: grooveLocalGWS - {88FED34C-F0CA-4636-A375-3CB6248B04CD} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Office12\GR99D3~1.DLL
O22 - SharedTaskScheduler: Component Categories cache daemon - {8C7461EF-2B13-11d2-BE35-3078302C2030} - C:\Windows\system32\browseui.dll
O23 - Service: Apple Mobile Device - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\bin\AppleMobileDeviceService.exe
O23 - Service: avast! iAVS4 Control Service (aswUpdSv) - ALWIL Software - C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\aswUpdSv.exe
O23 - Service: avast! Antivirus - ALWIL Software - C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\ashServ.exe
O23 - Service: avast! Mail Scanner - ALWIL Software - C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\ashMaiSv.exe
O23 - Service: avast! Web Scanner - ALWIL Software - C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\ashWebSv.exe
O23 - Service: Bonjour Service - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe
O23 - Service: CCProxy - Youngzsoft - C:\CCProxy\CCProxy.exe
O23 - Service: Google Update Service (gupdate1c9c328490dac0) (gupdate1c9c328490dac0) - Google Inc. - C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
O23 - Service: Google Software Updater (gusvc) - Google - C:\Program Files\Google\Common\Google Updater\GoogleUpdaterService.exe
O23 - Service: Distributed Transaction Coordinator MSDTCwercplsupport (MSDTCwercplsupport) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\acluiz.exe
O23 - Service: Realtek Audio Service (RtkAudioService) - Realtek Semiconductor - C:\Windows\RtkAudioService.exe
O23 - Service: StarWind AE Service (StarWindServiceAE) - Rocket Division Software - C:\Program Files\Alcohol Soft\Alcohol 120\StarWind\StarWindServiceAE.exe
O23 - Service: SuperProServer - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\spnsrvnt.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Vertrigo_Apache - Apache Software Foundation - C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\apache\bin\v_apache.exe
O23 - Service: Vertrigo_MySQL - Unknown owner - C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\mysql\bin\v_mysqld.exe

--
End of file - 10965 bytes
```

Comment: Scan your system using Malwarebytes AntiMalware

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I do when I find connections I don't recognize is trace them.

```
PS C:\Users\self> tracert 212.192.255.240

Tracing route to 212.192.255.240 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    10 ms    10 ms    12 ms  ... (omitted)
  2     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  110.ge-0-0-0.cr1.wdc1.speakeasy.net [69.17.83.57]
  3     8 ms     8 ms     7 ms  if-6-0-3-143.core4.AEQ-Ashburn.as6453.net [216.6.42.17]
  4   106 ms   106 ms   106 ms  if-5-0-0-908.core1.FR1-Frankfurt.as6453.net [216.6.42.74]
  5   105 ms   105 ms   106 ms  if-9-0-0.core1.FV0-Frankfurt.as6453.net [195.219.69.53]
  6   135 ms   135 ms   135 ms  if-7-0-0.core1.STK-Stockholm.as6453.net [195.219.131.45]
  7   135 ms   138 ms   135 ms  ix-4-0-1.core1.STK-Stockholm.as6453.net [195.219.131.22]
  8   150 ms   151 ms   150 ms  tug-1-gw.sth.runnet.ru [194.85.40.173]
  9   153 ms   152 ms   153 ms  bm18-1-gw.spb.runnet.ru [194.85.40.141]
 10   152 ms   152 ms   152 ms  tv11-1-gw.msk.runnet.ru [194.85.40.137]
 11   151 ms   152 ms   151 ms  m9-2-gw.msk.runnet.ru [194.85.40.53]
 12   151 ms   151 ms   151 ms  msu.msk.runnet.ru [194.190.255.234]
 13   150 ms   150 ms   151 ms  193.232.127.12
 14   152 ms   152 ms   152 ms  193.232.127.253
 15   153 ms   153 ms   151 ms  212.192.255.240

Trace complete.
```

As you can see, that host is in Russia, so unless you have legitimate business in Russia, it's probably malware, as you suspected.

In addition to [Hijack this](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/), which Jon Cage recommended, I also suggest [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx). Especially when the process that's hijacked is hosted by svchost.exe, Process Explorer will help you determine which services in particular are hosting the malware.

If you find that the anti-malware programs are unable to identify or remove the malware, you may have a sophisticated root kit that requires more advanced analysis. Consider using [Rootkit Revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx) to find the code, and (with caution) attempt to remove it.

If all of these fail to resolve the problem, what I would do for myself is buy a new hard drive, reinstall the operating system from scratch on the new hard drive, install an anti-malware software, and then move the data files (selectively) from the original hard drive to the new system, making sure to scan them beforehand. I realize this is involved and tedious, but is probably the only reliably effective way to remove sophisticated malware.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that antivirus / antimalware software failed to fix your problem (that should be your first line of defence)

!! SVCHOST (at least on my machine) is running either as SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SERVICE user - if it's running as normal user I think it's safe to kill it -- but remember you are doing everything on your own responsibility :) Just in case have Vista CD in handy :P !!

1. Try to kill the process that is trying to connect to the ip.
2. Remove all autostart entries on you computer - best tool for the job would be [Autoruns from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

If the the program will restart just after killing - you have another process somewhere that is watching over it - find it [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) helps here.

At this point you have 2 options (cause you cannot kill 2 processes at the same time):
1. Try to remove both processes files in in Safe Mode
2. Use [this](http://www.aumha.org/a/stubborn.php) article as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the Linux-based [Avira Rescue CD](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html) to be useful for removing the majority of infections (although it was unable to remove the one Conficker infection I've seen).

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in your HijackThis log that I'm unfamiliar with - are CCProxy and SuperProServer things you've installed? If you're not administering CCProxy, that could easily be used by an adversary to bounce traffic off of your host.

Also, the F2 line is suspicious to me. I'm not sure where that originates, so I can't provide any solid suggestions, but the fact that it's calling rundll suggests it could be running anything.

Also, it appears your DNS servers are in India. Is those the ones assigned by your ISP? I would investigate this as well.